# play-services-ads:18.1.0 Causing Fatal Error on Android 4

Tags: android, admob

The version 18.1.0 of play-services-ads is breaking badly on android 4.4.2 to 4.4.

Here's a sample fatal error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.VerifyError: c/d/b/a/g/a/FJ
        at c.d.b.a.g.a.KJ.f(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.0:2)
        at c.d.b.a.g.a.Sm.a(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.0:2)
        at c.d.b.a.g.a.bD.a(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.0:31)
        at c.d.b.a.g.a.NY.a(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.0:23)
```

Please help

Comment: I have the same issue on 18.1.1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342096, hoping for a fix soon but I'm looking into how to work around it at the moment - did you find a temporary fix you can share?

Comment: @magritte temporary fix is to revert to version 18.0.0

Comment: I tried that, actually I found version 18.0.0 has a ton of other issues. It's pretty annoying how unstable that SDK is. My current solution is to use 18.1.1 but disable the SDK completely for anyone on Android 4.*, not ideal, but there aren't that many people on Android 4.*, so the loss in ad revenue is acceptable for now and I need to get my Android vitals looking happier as I'm pretty sure these problems have tanked my app store rankings.

Comment: version 18.0.0 is working fine without errors, from my end

Comment: is 18.3.0 solved the problem ? Any idea

Comment: Yes, please could you give some updates? How about 18.2 or 18.3?