# java.lang.verifyError after updating to Admob version 18.1.1

Tags: android, admob

I updated from `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1`, and I am seeing the following error in android vitals:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: 
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdan.zzdt (zzdan.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbew.zzaf (zzbew.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzclu.zza (zzclu.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzww.zza (zzww.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd (InterstitialAd.java)
```

It appears to be only affecting older devices running android 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4.  Does anyone know what this error is?  I read that updating the min sdk version from 14 to 16 might help (I'm about to try that), but any insights appreciated.

**Update:** changing the min sdk version made no difference.  I'm still seeing this error and have recreated it on an old Galaxy S3 test device.  Swapping the Admob version back to 18.1.0 fixes it, so it's definitely an issue with that particular version.  Trying to see if I can code a workaround to at least stop the app from crashing.  Will report to the Admob team.

Comment: that's a tough one without much information. Can you report it to the Ads team?

Comment: Can you show your app level build.gradle?

Comment: even version 18.1.0 has that bug https://stackoverflow.com/q/57189415/6563022

Comment: I saw the same issue, and reverting to 18.1.0 fixed it as you saw too. It's allegedly fixed in the next release (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/cbr_oV4Yzfg/U32pn8LoCAAJ)

Comment: Still broken in 18.2.0...

Comment: Still broken in 18.3.0